# is there shorter way of calling non static method in c#?

Tags: c#, instance, non-static

I have a class `StringFormatter` which contains method `RemoveCharFromString`.

For a long time, I have been creating a new instance of a class and then use it like the following:

```
[...]
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
string exampleString = sf.RemoveCharFromString(inputString, '%');
[...]
```

Now I came to a point where I just have to use this method a single time in one class. I thought there might be a shorter way of accomplishing the above code such as:

```
[...]
string exampleString = new StringFormat.RemoveCharFromString(inputString, '%');
[...]
```

Is there something for that?

Comment: How about using `string.Replace("%", "")` ?

Comment: You can write extension method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: @julian bechtold: I'm curious - did you try your example?  Did it work?  You need `new StringFormatter()...`, but otherwise it looks OK. And yes, Selman Genç's suggestion sounds like it might be a better solution for this particular problem.

Comment: `new StringFormatter().RemoveCharFromString(inputString, '%');` You forgot the brackets.

Comment: no I did not try my example, this is more of a general question. Does this work @ Guy?

Comment: It looks like, even from the naming of the class, `StringFormatter` class is made up of pure methods. It may be better to change the usage of the class, and inject it using DI solutions

Comment: @AccessDenied but that contradicts the requirement "non static method". :)

Comment: @kennyzx it does not contradict to RemoveCharFromString which is non-static

Comment: Yes, it works. If you already wrote it, why didn't you try it? @julianbechtold

Comment: well thank you. I did not have the brackets () so VS did not give me intellisense which is why i thought it would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate a class and call one of it's methods directly - your second code sample just needs a parenthesis after the constructor:

```
string exampleString = new StringFormatter().RemoveCharFromString(inputString, '%');
```

However - there are things to consider here, without knowing the insides of the method:

1. The method's name suggests it's basically removing a specific char from the string - If it removes all occurrences of said char, why not just use `string.Replace()`?
2. Since this method seems to be getting all the information it needs from it's arguments and does not rely on, nor changes the state of the `StringFormatter` instance, why not make it a static method?

Comment: I wonder what was so wrong in my answer it got downvoted faster than I could read it...

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I wonder which one is faster string.Replace or RemoveCharFromString?

Comment: @Access Denied, you got the reason why i'm not using string.Replace ;)
with the static method, i'm not so sure if thats what I'm looking for in a Multithreaded application.. where this Method might be called from several threads at the same time.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You can write a benchmark and then suggest. How do you know which one is faster for this particular case. To my mind more specialized method to remove char should work faster.

Comment: @AccessDenied No, because I don't have access to the StringFormatter class... how can I benchmark a class I don't have access to?

Comment: @ZoharPeled OK, I thought it exists in CTS.

Comment: In a multithreaded environment where the method is static and it does not have any internal state, then you have nothing to worry about. In fact it is better to have them static

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the StringFormatter class is a bunch of methods which works on the type string. One option, could therefore be to consider to use extensions methods on the string type instead

```
public static class StringFormatter
{
    public static string RemoveCharFromString(this string value, char charToRemove)
    {
        //do your logic and then return a string 
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
var exampleString = inputString.RemoveCharFromString('%');
```